# Нужно циклом вычислить количество лет по достижении лимита

Tags: javascript

Предлагаю на будущее создать функцию getYears для банкира. Функция должна возвращать количество лет, для которого сумма средств, которые надо будет отдать банку для размера кредита amount под percent процентов годовых, не превысит ожидаемый лимит expectedLimit клиента.

Примеры:

- getYears(1600, 10, 2000) === 2 1600 + 160 + 176 < 2000;
- getYears(500, 3, 550) === 3

```
function getYears(amount, percent, expectedLimit) {
  // write code here
  let i = -1;
  let a = amount;

  while  (a <= expectedLimit){
    a +=amount * percent * 0.01;
    i++;
    
  }
  return i;
}
```

Всё до чего я смог додуматься.

Работает во всех проверяемых кейсах, кроме этого **"input: amount - 5000, percent - 5, expectedLimit - 6500
expected output: 5"** выводит 6 вместо 5.

Comment: А то, что процент накопительный, кто будет учитывать?

Comment: @Akina накопительность учтена как бы

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME все равно срабатывает не во всех кейсах

Comment: а процент не от оставшейся части займа платится?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getYears(amount, percent, expectedLimit) {
  let i = -1;
  let a = amount;

  while (a <= expectedLimit) {
    a += a * percent * 0.01; // "a * ...", a нe "amount * ..."
    i++;
  }

  return i;
}

console.log(getYears(1600, 10, 2000)) // 2 
console.log(getYears(500, 3, 550))    // 3
console.log(getYears(5000, 5, 6500))  // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    /* Мы имеем сумму - amount, 
фиксированный процент - percent, 
и ограничение - limit, сумму кот. не должны превысить. 

 - По условию мы должны написать функцию, которая посчитает максимальный срок, при котором финальная выплата не превысит лимит*/

function getYears(amount, percent, limit) {

// создадим переменную total - это то, что мы в конце выплатим

  let total = amount; 

/* вначале наша сумма совпадает с взятым кредитом
 и каждый год total будет увеличиваться*/

  let years = 0;

  // создадим цикл while, в котором мы будем сравнивать total с лимитом
  /* "до тех пор пока" total не превышает лимит мы будем добавлять еще один год */

  while (total <= limit) {  
  
// если сумма не превышает лимитов, то мы будем брать ее еще на один год

 years++;

 total += (total * percent) / 100; // увеличивается общая сумма

    /* total - увеличивается += на total умноженный на величину в процентах
  и поделенный на 100 */

  }
  
  /* в какой-то момент последний год будет лишним, поэтому результатом нашей функции будет years - 1 */

  return years - 1;
}

************************************

function getYears(amount, percent, limit) {
  let total = amount;

  let years = 0;

  while (total <= limit) {
    years++;
    total += (total * percent) / 100;
  }

  return years - 1;
}

console.log(getYears(500, 3, 550)); //3
console.log(getYears(1600, 10, 2000)); //2
console.log(getYears(5000, 5, 6500)); //5
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]